# Hashing of keys with statements or functions as values?

Tags: perl, hash

Can Hash Values be associated with statements or functions?

Let's say I have a list of keys and I wish to look up the value of an item in the hash table. Corresponding to the key/value detected, can we directly execute a set of statements?
(without iterating through the list of all keys/values)

I am looking for any solutions better than using function pointers.

Comment: What is your problem with using function pointers, and how do we know what you would consider to be *"better"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use anon functions as hash values,

```
my %hash = (
  func1 => sub { return "Hello"; },
  func2 => sub { return "world"; },
);

print $hash{func1}->(), " ", $hash{func2}->(), "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Certainly. You can write code like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dispatch = (
  aa => sub {
    print "AA\n";
  },
  bb => sub {
    print "BB\n";
  },
  cc => sub {
    print "CC\n";
  },
);

for (qw/ aa cc /) {
  $dispatch{$_}->();
}
```

**output**

```
AA
CC
```